# How do I add a class to Netbean's classpath (for syntax errors)?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm working on a project in Netbeans, and I downloaded some external libraries through Gradle. However, Netbeans doesn't find them. I tried adding it in Settings (add Jar), but it doesn't help

I don't mind that netbeans doesn't compile the code, I just type "gradle"  and java -jar ... in a command line.

My problem is that Nebeans shows syntax errors everywhere (it can't find class ...) and doesn't show the list of methods/properties of library objects.

Where else can I add Jar files in netbeans

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project node in the "Projects Window", choose "Properties", select the "Libraries" section and add the jar files you need.

More details in the manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/create_japps.htm#CHDFBFAD